# How to drag a drawn shape in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+

I have a program written in C#/WindowsForms that draws circles (nodes of a graph) on a Panel.
I want to drag one circle to another place.

I have a dictionary that goes

```
Dictionary NodeMap<Node,Point>;
```

So from this, and MouseDown event I can find out which node I am dragging.

The problem is that currently it doesn't drag the node, just repaint it in new position, so I have to click several times to move it.

My code for this part is:

```
private void pnlCanvas_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Node grabbedNode = new Node("-1");

        Point loc = e.Location;
        loc.X = (int) (loc.X * 1000.0 / pnlCanvas.ClientSize.Width);
        loc.Y = (int) (loc.Y * 1000.0 / pnlCanvas.ClientSize.Height);


        foreach (var n in NodeMap)
        {
            if ((Math.Abs(n.Value.X - loc.X) < (sldNodeSize.Value)) && (Math.Abs(n.Value.Y - loc.Y) < (sldNodeSize.Value)))
            {
                grabbedNode = n.Key;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (grabbedNode.Id != "-1")
        {
            NodeMap.Remove(grabbedNode);
            NodeMap.Add(grabbedNode, loc);
            DrawGraph((short)sldNodeSize.Value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: MouseDown is good for capturing of which node is grabbed.  The DrawGraph logic needs to be in MouseMove - which fires as the mouse is ... moved.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comment by John Arlen, I had to move setting new location and repainting to MouseMove, leaving MouseDown only for detecting node. Then, with a help of global Node object, and isDraggingNode boolean variable I was able to achievie my goal. Thanks! - rakoczyn